# Modulus and argument

Tags: complex-numbers

If I have a complex number $z$, with the modulus $2$ and argument $-\pi/3$. And I want to find $z^2$. I know the modulus will be $4$, but what will the argument be? Should I just add $-\pi/3$, with $-\pi/3$? In which I get $-2\pi/3$.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).
 What have you tried?

Comment: **Hint**: Use De Moivre’s Theorem to find powers of complex numbers.

Comment: $z$ is of modulus 2 and argument $-\frac{\pi}{3}$ then the exponantial form of $z$ is  $e^{\frac{-\pi}{3}}$ so $z^2=4e^{\frac{-2\pi}{3}}$ so $arg(z^2)=-\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $|z^2|=4$

Comment: To @MahmoudMrowi: perhaps you wanted to write $arg(z^2)=-\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $|z^2|=4$.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak yes, i edit it now

Answer (score 1):

Notice, when $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{z}&=\Re\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}\right)i\\
\\
&=\left|\text{z}\right|\exp\left(\left(2\pi\text{n}+\arg\left(\text{z}\right)\right)i\right)\\
\\
&=\left|\text{z}\right|\cos\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)\right)+\left|\text{z}\right|\sin\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)\right)i
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}

Where $\displaystyle\left|\text{z}\right|:=\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)}$, $\displaystyle0\le\arg\left(\text{z}\right)<2\pi$ and $\displaystyle\text{n}\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*
\begin{align*}
z_1&=r_1e^{i\theta_1}\\
z_2&=r_2e^{i\theta_2}\\
z_1z_2&=r_1e^{i\theta_1}r_2e^{i\theta_2}=r_1r_2e^{i\left(\theta_1+\theta_2\right)}
\end{align*}